# Swift: How to increment an element in an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to display different text within a label after a period of time using a timer, but cant increment the element of my custom type array.

Here is the code:

```
    import UIKit

    class WorkWorkoutViewOne: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var exerciseTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var instructionsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var exerciseImage: UIImageView!


var counter = 15
var timer: NSTimer?

var workoutExercisesShuffled = [Exercise]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let image: UIImage = workoutExercisesShuffled[0].filename!
    exerciseImage.image = image

    let titleLabel = workoutExercisesShuffled[0].name
    exerciseTitle.text = titleLabel

    let instructionsTitle = workoutExercisesShuffled[0].instructions
    instructionsLabel.text = instructionsTitle

    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "timerAction", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

var timerTwo: NSTimer?
var counterTwo = 15

func timerAction() {
    --counter
    timerLabel.text = "\(counter)"
    if (counter == 0) {
        timer?.invalidate()
        let image: UIImage = workoutExercisesShuffled[1].filename!
        exerciseImage.image = image

        let titleLabel = workoutExercisesShuffled[1].name
        exerciseTitle.text = titleLabel

        let instructionsTitle = workoutExercisesShuffled[1].instructions
        instructionsLabel.text = instructionsTitle

        timerLabel.text = "\(counterTwo)"

        var timerTwo = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "timerActionTwo", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
}
```

Repeating this method using timerThree, timerFour etc. seems clumbsy and unnecessary, so would like a way to increment the array values rather than having to call seperately in different functions.

Comment: just store a current exercise's index, which you will increment and use when retrieving an `Exercise` object from the array instead of a hardcoded number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it uses two methods and an index.

**Workflow**

- Initially `index` is set to 0 and `counter` is set to 15.
- `updateExercise()` is called.

  - The exercise UI is updated.
  - If `index` is 0 the `timer` is created.
- `timerAction()` is called after the timer fires.

  - The counter is decremented and the counter label is updated.
  - If `counter` is 0 and `index` is equal to the number of exercises -1  the timer is invalidated.
  - If `counter` is 0 and `index` < number of exercises -1 `index` is incremented, `counter` is reset to 15 and `updateExercise()` is called again.

---

```
    var counter = 15
    var index = 0

    var timer: NSTimer?

    var workoutExercisesShuffled = [Exercise]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      updateExercise()
    }

    func updateExercise() {
      let image: UIImage = workoutExercisesShuffled[index].filename!
      exerciseImage.image = image

      let titleLabel = workoutExercisesShuffled[index].name
      exerciseTitle.text = titleLabel

      let instructionsTitle = workoutExercisesShuffled[index].instructions
      instructionsLabel.text = instructionsTitle

      if index == 0  {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "timerAction", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
      }
    }

    func timerAction() {
      counter -= 1
      timerLabel.text = "\(counter)"
      if (counter == 0) {
        if index == workoutExercisesShuffled.count - 1 {
          timer!.invalidate()
          timer = nil
        } else {
          index += 1
          counter = 15
          updateExercise()
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this, but it should work.

```
import UIKit

class WorkWorkoutViewOne: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var exerciseTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var instructionsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var exerciseImage: UIImageView!

    var count = 15
    var index = 0
    var timer: NSTimer
    var countdown: NSTimer

    var workoutExercisesShuffled = [Exercise]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // TODO: load your exercises

        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(15, target: self, selector: "displayNewExercise", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func displayNewExercise() {

        countdown = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "displayCountdown", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        if (index < workoutExercisesShuffled.count) {

            exerciseImage.image = workoutExercisesShuffled[index].filename!
            exerciseTitle.text = workoutExercisesShuffled[index].name
            instructionsLabel.text = workoutExercisesShuffled[index].instructions

            ++index    

        }
        else {
            timer.invalidate()
            countdown.invalidate()
        }
    }

    func displayCountdown() {
        if(count > 0) {
            countDownLabel.text = String(--count)
        }
        else {
            countdown.invalidate()
            count = 15
        }
    }
}
```

Don't repeat yourself. A certain task can be done only by one function, the code for this particular task must not be elsewhere.